# Rails Validation with ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I've been going through the documentation for getting `ActiveRecord` validation working with `ActiveModel`. For some reason I am not seeing any validation results returned.

I have a set of models which instead of interfacing with `ActiveRecord` are interfacing through a custom API that will be sitting behind Rails.

The Model:

```
class ApiObject < ApiConnector
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :fieldName

  validates :fieldName, :presence => true
  def save
    #save method implementation
  end
end
```

The Controller:

```
def create
  @apiObject = ApiObject.new(params[:api_object])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @apiObject.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@apiObject, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @apiObject, :status => :created, :location => @apiObject }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @apiObject.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The Form:

```
<%= form_for :api_object, :url => '/apiobjectcontroller/' do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :fieldName, 'Field Name' %>
    <%= f.text_field :fieldName %>
    <%= f.submit 'Create'%>
<% end %>
```

I am following the code laid out here: [Rails ActiveModel Validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)

The method is correctly returning to the form because @apiObject.save is returning as false, but no validation response is coming back. I've checked the markup and the usual rails validation results are not returned. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fully answer:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3

In a nutshell: create your form with an instance variable + add the necessary code to display your errors.

Comment: I have added both and I am still getting nothing back when it returns. The errors collection is empty.

Comment: The errors collection is only filled out when valid? is called. Perhaps you have to manually call valid?

Comment: Thanks Scott that worked. After changing the form to use an instance variable I needed to add a call to valid?. Apparently it was not mentioned in the documentation on ActiveModel validation. Fortunately it is working now though.

Comment: Ha! I was updating my original answer to include that at the same time you were commenting! Well at least others will see the full solution.

Answer (score 5):

I have similar code that works, but I have an initialize method in my classes. Perhaps your model should be:

```
class ApiObject < ApiConnector
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :fieldName, :presence => true

  attr_accessor :fieldName

  def initialize(fieldName)
    @first_name = fieldName
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?
    # save method implementation to go here
    # ...
    true # if save successful, otherwise, false
  end
end
```

If the above works, and you end up having a lot of attributes to assign in your initializer, then you could use this old trick:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |name, value|
    instance_variable_set "@#{name}", value
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: Added a call to valid? in save implementation, so that errors collection will be filled out.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in the validation part of his code.

Comment: Thank you! High fives to the team! :-)

Comment: Rather than doing the if, else, couldn't you just return valid?

Comment: @stebooks It's simply an indicative method to suggest that the real `save` implementation should return `true` upon successful save or `false` if it failed. It's a nod to the spirit of the ActiveRecord API, which most Rubyists are used to.

Comment: @stebooks I've thought some more. Not really that clear, I agree. I'll update it.